# Where can I find/buy the Chinese Annals of Mathematics, Chinese Series, Volume 20 (2001)?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Where can I find/buy this journal?

> Chinese Annals of Mathematics, , Chinese Series, **20** (2001).

I looked everywhere but couldn't find it, the reason I'm looking for it is because I need to see the proof of the following Lemma I saw in an article : ([31] is a reference to the journal above.)

LEMMA (Lemma A.6 of Zhang and Wen [31] ). Suppose that the events $A_{1}, \ldots, A_{n}$ satisfy $\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{A_{i}}\right) \leqq c \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left\{A_{i}\right\} .$ Then :
$$
\left(1-P\left\{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}\right\}\right)^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} P\left\{A_{i}\right\} \leqq c P\left\{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}\right\}
$$

if anyone knows where I can acquire the journal or knows any toher reference that proves this Lemma it would be great, thanks !

Comment: Could you give us the full reference for the paper? Saying that it is reference 31 in some paper does not help too much.

Comment: @Gary someone has already found the paper I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is also known as *Chinese Annals of Mathematics Series A* (Series A are for papers written in Chinese, Series B is English, and no, they are not translation of each other), published by Fudan University in China.  Is [this](https://www.cnki.com.cn/Article/CJFDTotal-SXNZ200102010.htm) the article you are looking for (if you can't read Chinese, [this](http://www.airitilibrary.com/Publication/alDetailedMesh?DocID=sxnk200102011) has the title translated into English)?  Some of the Series A articles are translated into English and published in *Chinese Journal of Contemporary Mathematics* (Allerton Press Inc), so you might try your luck there.

Comment: that's exactly the title of the article I was looking for, thank you.